# EXCEL: Excel on my desktop when edited must update same excel on server

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my requirement: 
I have four people in my team, and I need all the four to update the excel sheet on their desktops. Once the excel sheet is saved , I need the data to be updated on excel sheet of same name on the server. Do we have any macro that can help here?

Say the excel is on the link http://cccc/excel1.xls. And all four team mates download this excel from server (excel11.xls) onto the desktop. Once they update the excel on the desktop, I need it to automatically update on the server. Can we do it through any macro?

Comment: Seems simpler to just use a shared drive. With multiple copies you may end up having more than one person doing changes at the same time. Any update could then potentially overwrite the changes made by someone else.

Comment: yes, but getting people to go onto the shared folder and update one after the other is getting really challenging :) so I thought of creating one this way so that it will avoid the need to check out the excel and then make changes and check in again...